# JS audio player, click list item to play

Tags: javascript, list, audio

I am working on an web audio player using html/css and javascript.

The player uses a list to store the songs currently, and displays the list at the bottom of the player as a playlist.

I want to make it so that when I click on a list item, the audio for that list item starts to play.

This is the code I have currently:

```
//Click Song Title

$('#playlist li').click(function(){
audio.play();

$('#play').hide();
$('#pause').show();
$('#duration').fadeIn(400);
showDuration();
});
```

It works, except that no matter which list item I click on it just plays the first list item's song. It also only works if the player is freshly loaded or the song is paused.

If you need to know what else is going on in the code let me know.

Here is my original definition of the audio element

```
//Create AUDIO OBJECT
audio = new Audio('http://localhost/beats/wp-content/themes/AG_1/html_5_audio_player/media/' + song);
```

Comment: Where are you assigning what `audio` is? Doesn't look like it ever changes so it'll just keep playing the original assignment.

Comment: I have added my original definition of the audio in my original post

Comment: `//Create AUDIO OBJECT
 audio = new Audio('http://localhost/beats/wp-content/themes/AG_1/html_5_audio_player/media/' + song);`

Comment: So audio never changes... you have to assign what audio is when you click on a song title.

Comment: So I also have play, next, and previous buttons. If I change the definition will it effect the functionality of those buttons? 

Should I give a new audio definition inside that click LI to play function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107670/discussion-between-alex-gray-and-blue-eyed-behemoth).

Answer (score 0):

Define audio when you know what audio is going to be... like when you click on a song.

```
//Click Song Title

$('#playlist li').click(function(){

//Create AUDIO OBJECT
audio = new Audio('http://localhost/beats/wp-content/themes/AG_1/html_5_audio_player/media/' +
     this.val()); // Not sure what the actual value is here, but you need to update what the file that is playing is.

audio.play();

$('#play').hide();
$('#pause').show();
$('#duration').fadeIn(400);
showDuration();
});
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I started to do but I'm also not sure what to change this value to. I tried the following code but it was a wrong guess =/ 

`$('#playlist li').click(function(){
 //Create AUDIO OBJECT
 audio = new Audio('http://localhost/beats/wp-content/themes/AG_1/html_5_audio_player/media/' +
      this.val($('#playlist li + song'))); // Not sure what the actual value is here, but you need to update what the file that is playing is.

 audio.play();

 $('#play').hide();
 $('#pause').show();
 $('#duration').fadeIn(400);
 showDuration();
});`

Comment: @AlexGray You really have to put all of your code in your question, or else I'm doing a lot of blind guessing.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'll post an answer with how I got it to work for anyone who is curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Click Song Title



$('#playlist li').click(function(){

audio.pause();
if(typeof audio !== "undefined" ) audio.src='http://localhost/beats/wp-content/themes/AG_1/html_5_audio_player/media/' +
     $(this).attr('song'); 

audio.play();

$('#play').hide();
$('#pause').show();
$('#duration').fadeIn(400);
showDuration();
$('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass("active");

});
```

That's the code I implemented with the rest to get it to work. I know that not posting the whole thing might not be of much use, but maybe it will help someone.